# What does Crash say when he dies

Tags: crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

I'm playing Crash Bandicoot remastered for the PS4 and when I fall into water or a pit, Crash mumbles something like "... to the devil". Does anyone know what he really says?
It doesn't happen every time, seems only to happen when falling in the same pit often

Comment: I watched a few videos of Crash death animations, and for the pit ones, I don't hear him say a thing.  Does it happen every time?

Comment: [Related.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBfMEUiobfE)

Comment: Is this specific to any single game in the collection?

Comment: After having played this extensively in the last week, I can't say I remember any instance where he does say anything upon death, at least not in the first two games. When he takes a hit (when he has an Aku Aku mask) he does say something, but it just sounds like gibberish.

Comment: AFAIK you get free Aku-Aku when you die too much, and getting Aku-Aku in normal circumstances will produce gibberish voice. Perhaps you misheard that?

Answer (score 1):

When Crash dies he typically utters single-word phrases (see below) or makes unintelligible sounds.

According to [WikiFur](https://en.wikifur.com/wiki/Crash_Bandicoot) in discussing Crash Bandicoot's speech:

> He does not speak much, but his style of talking consists of gibberish, which the other characters can understand, and simple words like "Coco" and "Pancakes", and he says "Whoa!" in the games when he dies.

According to the [Fandom](https://crashbandicoot.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_quotes_in_Crash_Bandicoot_N._Sane_Trilogy) page regarding the N Sane Trilogy, these are all the phrases Crash Bandicoot says:

> - "Uh oh!"
> - "Bada-baaaah!!!"
> - [ending cutscene] "Yeee-HAW!"
> - "Oh!"
> - "Whoa!"

However, Crash was never intended to be a particularly talkative character. From [Digital Spy](https://www.digitalspy.com/videogames/a806253/20-things-you-didnt-know-about-crash-bandicoot/):

> There's a reason why Crash never utters more than a "Whoa" or a "Yeehah" in the series.
>
> "We felt that he should be goofy and fun-loving, and never talk –  on the theory that voices for video game characters were always lame, negative, and distracted from identification with them," explained Crash Bandicoot co-creator Andy Gavin in an extensive [blog post](https://all-things-andy-gavin.com/2011/02/03/making-crash-bandicoot-part-2/).

The quote within the quoted text comes from [here](https://all-things-andy-gavin.com/2011/02/03/making-crash-bandicoot-part-2/).

Answer (score 0):

He doesn't say anything. It's gibberish that occasionally sounds like English, but it isn't.